# Setting priorities on HTML Events

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling

We have a Web system that uses a combination of OnBlur and OnMouseDown events. Unfortunately, for a strange reason the OnMouseDown event handler is being triggered before calling the OnBlur event handler.

This is not what we want. Instead, we want to always call the OnBlur event handler prior to calling the onMouseDown event handler. Is there a way to do so, perhaps giving the onBlur a higher priority?

Previously, instead of using the onMouseDown event handler we had the onclick event. However, this posed a number of problems especially due to the single-threaded nature of JavaScript.

Comment: Definitely it is. It is always difficult to write code across multiple browsers. However, we can safely make the assumption that we are targeting IE. 

What is also strange is that when I replace the onmousedown with the onclick event then what happens is that only the onblur event handler is called and that is fine, however the actual onclick handler is not called when I am on a field with the onblur event set.   

With the onmousedown we are almost there but the onblur event is getting triggered after the onmousedown which is not what we want.

Comment: I think mousedown then blur is pretty standard in this case. Remember an onmousedown event handler may return false, in which case the focus change doesn't happen. onclick should generally work; maybe post the code that's not working there?

Comment: Have you checked what happens if somebody presses the mouse button, holds it down, and moves it away from the target? In that case, depending on the draggability of the target, you may well have a mousedown event but no change in focus and therefore no blur event. That is why the blur event happens after mousedown: it's only when the mousedown turns into a click that the focus is moved and the previously-focused element is blurred. (Although draggability can change things...) I would suggest changing your approach to work with the grain rather than against it.

Comment: @NickFitz, that is a spot-on analysis! In fact, what is happening is that when there is no change in focus the onblur event happens after the onmousedown. 

However, I have managed to work now. What I did is that I added a return statement, return false, in the onblur event handler and then the onmousedown event is triggered after the onblur. I am still a bit confused here but it did work.

Comment: what happened when you press Tab? is it still fire onmousedown before onblur?

Answer (score 0):

Catch `event #2`, fire `event #1`. Then let `event #2` go through.

.. Catch-and-release pattern :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you kindly provide a simple example or a pointer for further info on this?

Comment: @roosteronacid, what if only one of the events happens?  Do you still call the body method?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to fake it by using a status variable. It's a bit dirty, but it works: the meat of doImportantStuff will only be run once.

```
var importantStuffDone = false;
function doImportantStuff(){
     if(!importantStuffDone){
          // Do something important
          importantStuffDone = true;
     }
}

function doOnBlur(){
     // This function gets bound to the blur event
     doImportantStuff();
     // Do other blur stuff
}
function doOnMouseDown(){
     // This function gets bound to the mousedown event
     doImportantStuff();
     // Do other mousedown stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got your solution but what we want is that the onBlur event is always called prior to calling the onmousedown event. So the gist of the question is more about changing Javascript Event handling priority or precedence.

Comment: You can't; and even if you could, legacy browsers' implementation of event systems are so different that it'd end up breaking in something else. The best you can do is fake it, like this.